# Version number of NuGet pacakge specified in .csproj doesn't match version number of package

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I've generated a new NuGet package and when I add it to a project the reference is wrong. This is kind of hard to describe but I'll do my best. The last version of this package was 3.3.11.0. I modified the code of the package, changed the assemblyinfo.cs to 3.64.1:

[image]

Changed the version in the .nuspec file:

[image]

Recompiled and ran NuGet pack to create the package and NuGet init to place it on our share and yet when I add the package to my project and the "Include" version is wrong:

[image]

**What the heck is going on? I've been working with creating NuGet Packages for years and I've never seen anything like this.**

The version of the actual generated .dll is correct as well:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 1 2/7/20**
Based on feedback I tried updating the major version number, but for some reason the version in the "Reference Include" section is always one behind the actual version number:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the Version Number you are setting it to.

Changing the minor number is not a breaking change and backwards compatible to the previous one.

What happens if you change the major number so NuGet knows it is a breaking change version.  Might update the version number then as that version, 3.3.11.0 is no longer backwards compatible. Also what happens if you uninstall and reinstall instead of upgrading?

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling. That didn't help. So I tried incrementing the major number and got limited success. But for some reason the version on the <Reference Include line is always one behind the actual version??? I'll update the original question with my results. The solution still won't build.